# Is there a way to make a new scene through script || Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

Hello is there a way to simply create a new scene through script and name it when a new player starts, it’s for a multiplayer game I have brainstorming but this is kinda the starting point for me.

Comment: [`SceneManager.CreateScene`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.CreateScene.html) ... could probably have been found by googling .. as I just did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the way to make a scene:

```
 Scene newScene = SceneManager.CreateScene("My New Scene");
```

Comment: Dude, thank you so much. You are a life saver. I don’t know how I didn’t think of that.

Comment: Can you sort those scenes into a folder? Also, can you use that line of code in a function? Like Void CreateScene()

Comment: If the answer is usefful please mark it as valid. About your new question , yes you can use it in any Unity monobehaviour function.